# MVC : Pass Model from View through JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have the following model in my view that I am passing to it:

```
    @model DB.Models.Employees
```

after the user updates the model, I like to pass the model through Jquery.
I have the following code - note that url is the path to my controller:

```
     $.post(url, { employeeinfo: '@Model' },
     .....
```

@Model did not pass the whole model. I get a null value when I view the content of it in the controller.

I am using MVC .NET

Comment: What language/framework/etc. are you using?  It's not clear what you're talking about.  Can you post a more complete code sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the model values and put them in a JSON object.  Then it will send your model to the server.

```
    var emp = {
        SearchType: $('#txtFirstName').val(),
        SelectedAccounts: $('#txtLastName').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "UpdateEmp",
        data: parms,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function () {
            document.location = 'ErrorThrown';
        }
```

Here is a good article on binding your to your model after it is sent.
[model binding](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx)